# Configuring System Policies for Minimum Passcode Restrictions

Tags: windows-7, security-policy

Is there a system security policy in Windows that I can use to specifically state minimum passcode requirements for an account passcode?  When I was looking in the security policies i did not see any, but I wasn't looking extremely hard.

The OS is Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd>, then type in `secpol.msc`

Then navigate to `Account Policies` -> `Password Policies`

From there you can modify password policies and specifications

Also Outlined in this document: [Microsoft How-To](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Change-password-policy-settings)

Comment: Small consideration that I'm fond of pointing out: it's not necessary to use the Run command for this sort of thing post-Vista.  You can just put it in the start menu search and it'll find it right away for you.

Comment: Ahh, i missed that, was looking under a different subset of security policies, i'll check there once i'm back on that system that i'm setting this on, and get back to you.

Comment: @Shinrai you're right. But then again once Windows 8 comes out and they ditch our friend the start menu, trusty Ctrl+R will (hopefully) still work

Comment: I know this isn't an issue for the OP here, but it may be worth noting that not all MSCs are included in all editions of Windows.  I believe `secpol.msc` is not available in Home editions.

Comment: @BrandonKreisel - Search functionality is still intact on the Metro start screen, one of the few decent things about it.

Comment: True, I like how you worded that. I wish it would just lump the search together instead of seperating out into apps,files, and settings.